# Need help starting with Tatsu to parse grammar

Tags: tatsu

I am getting a Tatsu error

"tatsu.exceptions.FailedExpectingEndOfText: (1:1) Expecting end of text"

running a test, using a grammar I supplied - it is not clear what the problem is.

In essence, the statement calling the parser is:

```
ast = parse(GRAMMAR, '(instance ?FIFI Dog)')
```

The whole python file follows:

```
GRAMMAR = """

@@grammar::SUOKIF

KIF      = {KIFexpression}* $ ;

WHITESPACE = /\s+/ ;
StringLiteral = /['"'][A-Za-z]+['"']/ ;
NumericLiteral = /[0-9]+/ ;
Identifier = /[A-Za-z]+/ ;
LPAREN = "(" ;
RPAREN = ")" ;
QUESTION = "?" ;
MENTION = "@" ;
EQUALS = "=" ;
RARROW = ">" ;
LARROW = "<" ;
NOT = "not"|"NOT" ;
OR = "or"|"OR" ;
AND = "and"|"AND" ;
FORALL = "forall"|"FORALL" ;
EXISTS = "exists"|"EXISTS" ;
STRINGLITERAL = {StringLiteral} ;
NUMERICLITERAL = {NumericLiteral} ;
IDENTIFIER = {Identifier} ;

KIFexpression
     = Word
       | Variable
       | String
       | Number
       | Sentence
       ;

Sentence = Equation
       | RelSent
       | LogicSent
       | QuantSent
       ;

LogicSent
     = Negation
       | Disjunction
       | Conjunction
       | Implication
       | Equivalence
       ;

QuantSent
     = UniversalSent
       | ExistentialSent
       ;

Word     = IDENTIFIER ;

Variable = ( QUESTION | MENTION ) IDENTIFIER ;

String   = STRINGLITERAL ;

Number   = NUMERICLITERAL ;

ArgumentList
     = {KIFexpression}*
     ;

VariableList
     = {Variable}+
     ;

Equation = LPAREN EQUALS KIFexpression KIFexpression RPAREN ;

RelSent  = LPAREN ( Variable | Word ) ArgumentList RPAREN ;

Negation = LPAREN NOT KIFexpression RPAREN ;

Disjunction
     = LPAREN OR ArgumentList RPAREN
     ;

Conjunction
     = LPAREN AND ArgumentList RPAREN
     ;

Implication
     = LPAREN EQUALS RARROW KIFexpression KIFexpression RPAREN
     ;

Equivalence
     = LPAREN LARROW EQUALS RARROW KIFexpression KIFexpression RPAREN
     ;

UniversalSent
     = LPAREN FORALL LPAREN VariableList RPAREN KIFexpression RPAREN
     ;

ExistentialSent
     = LPAREN EXISTS LPAREN VariableList RPAREN KIFexpression RPAREN
     ;

"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pprint
    import json
    from tatsu import parse
    from tatsu.util import asjson

    ast = parse(GRAMMAR, '(instance ?FIFI Dog)')
    print('# PPRINT')
    pprint.pprint(ast, indent=2, width=20)
    print()

    print('# JSON')
    print(json.dumps(asjson(ast), indent=2))
    print()
```

Can anyone help me with a fix?

Answer (score 3):

I can see two problems with that grammar.

As written in [man pages](https://tatsu.readthedocs.io/en/stable/syntax.html), rule names that start with upper case character have special meaning. Change all the rule names to lower case.

Also let's review `IDENTIFIER` rule:

```
IDENTIFIER = {Identifier} ;
```

This means that identifier can be used multiple times, or may be missing at all. Remove the closure by defining `IDENTIFIER` directly:

```
IDENTIFIER = /[A-Za-z]+/ ;
```

You can do the same for `NUMERICLITERAL` and `STRINGLITERAL`.

When I did those steps, the expression could be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the name of the "start" symbol to `parse()`.

You can also define:

```
start = KIF ;
```

in the grammar.

Comment: I added "start = KIF ;" but it made no difference. I still get error:

tatsu.exceptions.FailedExpectingEndOfText: (1:1) Expecting end of text :
(instance ?FIFI Dog)
^